# generating times list with step in elixir

Tags: elixir

I have such data as

```
[
  %{since: ~T[13:30:00], till: ~T[14:30:00]},
  %{since: ~T[10:30:00], till: ~T[11:30:00]}
]
```

I am trying to generate timeslots between since and till (both including) with the step of 15 minutes.

so the above data will result in this

```
[~T[10:30:00], ~T[10:45:00], ~T[11:00:00], ~T[11:15:00], ~T[11:30:00], ~T[13:30:00], ~T[13:45:00], ~T[14:00:00], ~T[14:30:00]]
```

I have tried this so far.

```
Enum.map(data, fn(slot) ->
  duration = Time.diff(slot.till, slot.since) / 900 |> trunc()
  Enum.reduce(1..duration, [slot.since], fn _d, acc ->
    step = acc |> List.last |> Time.add(900)
    if Time.diff(step, slot.till) > 0 do
      acc ++ [Time.add(step, 900)]
    else
      acc
    end
  end)
end)
```

but this only gives me

```
[[~T[13:30:00]], [~T[10:30:00]]]
```

is there any nice and easy approach for this? I have looked at Timex but it's step feature is not useful in this case. any help would be great thank you.

update:

**this works**

```
Enum.map(slots, fn slot ->
  duration = (Time.diff(slot.till, slot.since) / 900) |> trunc()

  Enum.reduce(1..duration, [slot.since], fn _d, acc ->
    step = acc |> List.last() |> Time.add(900)

    if Time.diff(step, slot.till) < 0 do
      [acc | [step]]
    else
      [acc | [slot.till]]
    end
  end)
end)
|> List.flatten()
|> Enum.sort()
```

but still if something more to it or any better approach, that would be appreciated as well.

the above gives such results before flattening and sorting.

```
[
  [
    [
      [[[~T[13:30:00]], ~T[13:45:00.000000]], ~T[14:00:00.000000]],
      ~T[14:15:00.000000]
    ],
    ~T[14:30:00.000000]
  ],
  [
    [
      [[[~T[10:30:00]], ~T[10:45:00.000000]], ~T[11:00:00.000000]],
      ~T[11:15:00.000000]
    ],
    ~T[11:30:00.000000]
  ]
]
```

Comment: FWIW, https://hexdocs.pm/tempus/getting-started.html

Comment: Please stop corrupting the correct answer; the step in ranges is specified with `//step` notation. https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Range.html

Answer (score 2):

It’s easier to deal with a range with step. To do this, just convert times to seconds from the midnight, use the range, and then convert it back to time instances.

```elixir
data
|> Enum.flat_map(fn %{since: since, till: till} ->
  [since, till] =
    [since, till]
    |> Enum.map(&Time.to_seconds_after_midnight/1)
    |> Enum.map(&elem(&1, 0))
  Enum.map(since..till//900, &Time.from_seconds_after_midnight/1)
end)
|> Enum.sort(Time)  
#⇒ [~T[10:30:00], ~T[10:45:00], ~T[11:00:00], ~T[11:15:00], ~T[11:30:00],
#    ~T[13:30:00], ~T[13:45:00], ~T[14:00:00], ~T[14:15:00], ~T[14:30:00]]
```

Please note, that for cases when the slot overlaps midnight, this solution should be extended with a conditional, taking this into account.